# Docker image save how to check if exist before load?

Tags: docker, docker-image

This way I can make a backup of an existing docker image to a safe place:

```
docker save  -o  /backitup/myimage.tar   myimage:v1
```

Then I can restore the image to another host or on the same with:

```
cat  /backitup/myimage.tar  | docker import --message "New image imported from tarball" - myimage:v1
```

But how will I know if the same image is already on the host maybe with a different name?

```
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
myimage             v1                  1b6ef4d470ef   3 seconds ago        577MB
stillmyimage        dupe                a9a1468fdebf   4 minutes ago        577MB
```

Comment: Is using an image registry at all an option?  `docker pull` knows how to do this on its own, and it'll be much more convenient than trying to move tar files around.  (The opposite of `docker save` is `docker load`; you shouldn't ever need `docker import`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command replace the import and does exactly the job, load with name and don't create new if exist:

```
docker load < /backitup/myimage.tar
```

> Loaded image: myimage:v1